# Unable to get Product custom image role in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, media-images

i have created new image role name "tiles_images", i product listing page i want to show tile_image only , for this i have done below code but that seems not working

i am using below code in my `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

```
$customIcon = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tiles_images')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
print_r($customIcon);
```

**but it seems not working please help what i am missing**

Comment: Hello i cannot comment but looking at your question your role is tile_image and you are trying to get the attribute tiles_images. Is it just that you are mispelling your attribute code here?

Comment: no i am using correct spelling some mistake in posting question

Comment: @user1799722 Have you got the solution?

Comment: @user1799722 where do you want to show that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same issue if you have created attribute same way as @AliHussain mention then you have to just need to change one thing in attribute management using inspect element change the value of `used_in_product_listing` attribute value to `yes`

another way is if you have not set value for your attribute in all products then delete that attribute and while creating attribute before selecting attribute type just go to the `Storefront Properties` and select `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes` and then got to `Properties` tab and add required details.

[screenshot of Storefront Proerties tab](https://prnt.sc/pq9hqb)

Hope this will fix your issue.

**UPDATE**

> **Not Recommended**

use below query to change the value.

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET used_in_product_listing=1 where attribute_id=(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE `attribute_code`='tiles_images' and `entity_type_id` = 4)
```

Comment: it is image attribute : http://prnt.sc/pqhav8

Comment: you have to just need to change one thing in attribute management using inspect element change the value of `used_in_product_listing` attribute value to `yes`

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: You most welcome,,,

Comment: So it's a bug in the core Magento community. There is no way to set `used_in_product_listing` from the admin panel.

Comment: For media Image type they hide the Storefront Properties tab so we can not set value

Answer (score 1):

In theme's `view.xml` file declare your image attribute:

```
<image id="product_tiles_image" type="tiles_image">
    <width>338</width>
    <height>338</height>
</image>
```

Create an attribute like this in a data patch:

```
namespace Your\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddImageAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'tiles_image', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Tiles Images',
            'input' => 'media_image',
            'frontend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
            'required' => false,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Then on product page images tagged with `tiles_image` you can load like this in `product/list.phtml`:

```
$image = $block->getImage($_product, 'product_tiles_image');
$tilesImageHtml = null;
if (!empty($_product->getData('tiles_image'))) {
    $tilesImageHtml = $image->toHtml();
}
echo $tilesImageHtml ? $tilesImageHtml : ''
```

Comment: where to do this file name for "Create an attribute like this in a data patch"

Comment: `app/code/Your/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/AddImageAttribute.php`, check in core for example `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/Patch/Data/*`.

Comment: See my updated reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add Comment.
You have called the right way, that's how we get value of custom attributes.
Can you show what you have selected here and can you just simply show configuration of your attribute from here.

[image: Product Attribute Creation From Admin]

Considering you have a media image can you try this and check:

```
$productImageAttr = $_product->getCustomAttribute( 'tiles_images' );
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
->init($_product, 'tiles_images')
->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());

<img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getTitle()) ?>" />
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pprvx7

Comment: I have updated my answer, can u try this?